# Sort the array by category and name in ascending order

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var productMaster = [
    {id:'A441', name:'Pepsi',category:'Soft Drink', price:15, quantity:2},
    {id:'B234', name:'Coke', category:'Soft Drink', price:10, quantity:8},
    {id:'A617', name:'Mirinda', category:'Soft Drink', price:20, quantity:20},
    {id:'B003', name:'Sprite', category:'Soft Drink', price:16, quantity:5},
    {id:'B225', name:'Minute Maid', category:'Soft Drink', price:25, quantity:12},
    {id:'A742', name:'5Star', category:'Chocloate', price:10, quantity:3},
    {id:'B388', name:'Appy', category:'Soft Drink', price:35, quantity:9},
    {id:'A899', name:'Gems', category:'Chocloate', price:12, quantity:11},
    {id:'B635', name:'KitKat', category:'Chocloate', price:15, quantity:7},
    {id:'B408', name:'Perk', category:'Chocloate', price:8, quantity:15},
    {id:'A354', name:'Dairy Milk', category:'Chocloate', price:30, quantity:4}
]

productMaster.sort(compareName);
console.log(JSON.stringify(productMaster));

function compareName(prod1, prod2) {
   if (prod1.name > prod2.name)
        return 1;
   if (prod1.name == prod2.name)
        return 0;
   if (prod1.name < prod2.name)
        return -1;
}
```

> I have sorted this array by name in ascending order.But i dont know how to sort it so the Products within the same category are sorted by name.
> So the output should have the products with category Chocolate followed by products with category Soft Drink.

Comment: Sort array of Objects based on multiple instance variables in javascript. Please do a google search for this

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `category` values first return the compare result if they are not the same.
If categories are the same, compare the name and return the name comparison result.

And it will be sorted by category first and under same category, it will be sorted by name.

And for string comparison, you can use `String.prototype.localeCompare`.

```js
var productMaster = [
  { id: 'A441', name: 'Pepsi', category: 'Soft Drink', price: 15, quantity: 2 },
  { id: 'B234', name: 'Coke', category: 'Soft Drink', price: 10, quantity: 8 },
  { id: 'A617', name: 'Mirinda', category: 'Soft Drink', price: 20, quantity: 20 },
  { id: 'B003', name: 'Sprite', category: 'Soft Drink', price: 16, quantity: 5 },
  { id: 'B225', name: 'Minute Maid', category: 'Soft Drink', price: 25, quantity: 12 },
  { id: 'A742', name: '5Star', category: 'Chocloate', price: 10, quantity: 3 },
  { id: 'B388', name: 'Appy', category: 'Soft Drink', price: 35, quantity: 9 },
  { id: 'A899', name: 'Gems', category: 'Chocloate', price: 12, quantity: 11 },
  { id: 'B635', name: 'KitKat', category: 'Chocloate', price: 15, quantity: 7 },
  { id: 'B408', name: 'Perk', category: 'Chocloate', price: 8, quantity: 15 },
  { id: 'A354', name: 'Dairy Milk', category: 'Chocloate', price: 30, quantity: 4 }
];

console.log(productMaster.sort(compareName));

function compareName(prod1, prod2) {
  const categoryCompare = prod1.category.localeCompare(prod2.category);
  return categoryCompare === 0 ? prod1.name.localeCompare(prod2.name) : categoryCompare;
}
```